# Windows 8.1 Lightbox Effect

Tags: windows-8.1, lightbox

I want to use lightbox effect with windows 8.1 xaml, i googled it but cant find anything.

I want to a search button and when it click, lightbox popup will open.

Is there any way i can do it?

Comment: Can you screenshot this effect?  Just so we can get an idea.

Comment: it will like this [link](http://www.formget.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/lightbox-contact-form.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found solution my problem.I use  WinRT InputDialog.

You can find example this [WinRT](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Thanks